# Vue JS dynamic content based on link

Tags: navigation, vue.js, vuejs2

I am totally newbie with Vueand I am trying to figure out how can I render dynamic content based on link click. I am getting an error message: **Property or method "setLink" is not defined on the instance but referenced during render. Make sure to declare reactive data properties in the data option.**

Here is my VUE code:

```
Vue.component('navigation', {
            template: '#navigation'
        })

        Vue.component('home', {
            template: '#home'
        })

        Vue.component('about', {
            template: '#about'
        })

        var app = new Vue({
            el: '#app',

            component: {
                navigation
            },


            data: {
                currentView: 'home'
            },

            methods: {
                setLink: function(link) {
                    this.currentView = link;
                }
            }
        })
```

and I have div with id app:

```
<div id="app">
        <navigation></navigation>
        <div class="container">
            <componet :is="currentView"></component>    
        </div>
    </div>
```

In navigation I have a tag with v-on:click="setLink('someLink')" function. Maybe someone knows where the issue could be? Thank you

Comment: You need to define a `setLink` method in your `navigation` component. Even though that component's tag is within #app, it doesn't have references to the main #app component's methods

Answer (score 0):

Your `navigation` component doesn't have a method called `setLink`, but you are referencing a `setLink` method in that component's template. That's why you're getting that error.

If you're trying to change the main component's `currentView` property, you can instead emit an event (say `changeView`) from the `navigation` component when a link is clicked:

```
<div v-on:click="$emit('changeView', 'someLink')"></div>
```

Then, listen for that event in the main component's scope, on the tag for your `navigation` component:

```
<navigation v-on:changeView="setLink($event)"></navigation>
```

Here, the `$event` variable is what got sent as the value of the `changeView` event (`'someLink'` in the example).